# Is there an easy way to count the number of installed apps in my Android phone?

Tags: resource-monitoring

Maybe this info is in some file. I can also have it mounted in my computer and run a bunch of linux commands.

Answer (score 3):

Was about to say the same as Firelord – he missed the "ease" part, by the way, and has you counting lines manually. Rather try `adb shell pm list packages -3 |wc -l` (when on Windows, better use quotes: `adb shell "pm list packages -3 |wc -l"`). Takes a few seconds, and then shows *the number*.

Example, with one of my test devices:

```
adb shell "pm list packages -3 |wc -l"
```

Output: 15

Comment: It appears that `wc` is part of BusyBox and doesn't come with Android. You might want to verify and mention that in the answer. :)

Comment: @Firelord Oh. So what: "if `wc` is not found, please move the closing double-quotes to right after the `3` (`adb shell "pm list packages -3" |wc -l`), should work fine in the given example (Linux host ;)